# Accessing nested JSON using PHP

Tags: php, html, json, web-services

I've created the most part and it's working fine. But this is the only JSON that is nested. How do I access it? I've been trying for the longest time, I think I may have a brain freeze because I thought it would be so simple.

Here is the code to GET all reservations from the JSON file:

```
 GET - Gets all Reservation by Status
        $app->get('/reservation/:status', function($status) {
            $dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler();
            $dbHandler->connect();
            $reservationArray = $dbHandler->runQueryWithOneParam('SELECT * FROM RestaurantDB.Reservation WHERE STATUS = ?', "s", $status);


            $response = array();
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["reservations"] = array();
            while ($reservation = $reservationArray->fetch_assoc()) {
                $tmpReservation = array();
                $tmpReservation["ID"] = $reservation["ID"];
                $tmpReservation["UserName"] = $reservation["UserName"];
                $tmpReservation["NoOfPeople"] = $reservation["NoOfPeople"];
                $tmpReservation["DateOfReservation"] = $reservation["DateOfReservation"];
                $tmpReservation["TimeOfReservation"] = $reservation["TimeOfReservation"];
                $tmpReservation["Status"] = $reservation["Status"];
                $tmpReservation["TotalAmount"] = $reservation["TotalAmount"];
                $tmpReservation["SpecialRequirement"] = $reservation["SpecialRequirement"];
                $tmpReservation["Details"] = array();

                $reservationDetailArray = $dbHandler->runQueryWithOneParam('SELECT * FROM RestaurantDB.ReservationDetail WHERE ReservationID = ?', "i", $reservation["ID"]);

                while ($reservationDetail = $reservationDetailArray->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $tmpReservationDetails = array();
                    $tmpReservationDetails["ItemID"] = $reservationDetail["ItemID"];
                    $tmpReservationDetails["Quantity"] = $reservationDetail["Quantity"];
                    $tmpReservationDetails["SubTotal"] = $reservationDetail["SubTotal"];
                    array_push($tmpReservation["Details"], $tmpReservationDetails);
                }

                array_push($response["reservations"], $tmpReservation);
            }

            $dbHandler->disconnect();

            echoResponse(200, $response);
        });
```

The JSON is displayed as..

```
{
    "ID": 5,
    "UserName": "Coca Cola",
    "NoOfPeople": 2,
    "DateOfReservation": "1.79",
    "TimOfReservation": null,
    "Status": null,
    "TotalAmount": null,
    "SpecialRequirement": 0,
    "Details": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "ItemID": 3,
            "Quantity": 2,
            "SubTotal": ""
        },
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "ItemID": 4,
            "Quantity": 2,
            "SubTotal": 1.2
        }
    ]
}
```

For example I can display the reservation status using the `$reservation ["Status"]` but I don't seem to know how to get any of the fields from

```
   "Details": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "ItemID": 3,
            "Quantity": 2,
            "SubTotal": ""
        },
```

Here is the PHP code..

```
<?php
    include ('libs\WsURLs.php');
    include ('libs\WsConsumer.php');

    $wsConsumer = new WsConsumer ();

    $_POST = array ();

    $result = $wsConsumer->executeGET ( GET_RESERVATION );
    $reservations = $result ["reservations"];

    // Populating the table     

    foreach ( $reservations as $reservation) {
    echo ('<tr>');
    echo ('<td>' . $reservation ["Status"] . '</td>');  
    echo ('</tr>');
?>
```

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`$reservation["Details"]` is an array, you access the array elements:

```
$reservation["Details"][$i]["ItemID"]
```

is the Item ID of the i'th item in the reservation.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the reservation details

```
foreach($reservation ["Details"] as $key=>value)
```

Answer (score 0):

See this example you can go through the array and extract the values:

```
<?php


$json = '{
    "ID": 5,
    "UserName": "Coca Cola",
    "NoOfPeople": 2,
    "DateOfReservation": "1.79",
    "TimOfReservation": null,
    "Status": null,
    "TotalAmount": null,
    "SpecialRequirement": 0,
    "Details": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "ItemID": 3,
            "Quantity": 2,
            "SubTotal": ""
        },
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "ItemID": 4,
            "Quantity": 2,
            "SubTotal": 1.2
        }
    ]
}';

 $data = json_decode($json, true);

 for($i = 0; $i < count($data['Details']); $i++) {

    echo '<p>';

    foreach($data['Details'][$i] as $key => $value) {
       echo $key . ' -> ' . $value . '<br>';    
    }    

    echo '</p>';
}
```

In your case you can do that:

```
 $id_search = 2;

   foreach ( $reservations as $reservation) {
     for($i = 0; $i < count($reservation['Details']); $i++) {

if($id_search ==  $reservation['Details'][$i]['ID']) {

            echo '<p>';

            foreach($reservation['Details'][$i] as $key => $value) {
               echo $key . ' -> ' . $value . '<br>';    
            }    

            echo '</p>';
}

   }     
    }
```

Comment: Dude that is amazing. It managed to retrieve the data for all reservationId's! However I only want to receive the data that matches a specific reservationId. I have a table rows in which I have a buttons next to every reservationId. I need it only bring back the data relevant to that reservationId. Does that make any sense?

Comment: @user3081458 you got some advance?